# How to remove/delete akeneo?

Tags: ubuntu, delete-file, akeneo

Is there any way to delete akeneo from ubuntu.

> cd /tmp && wget wget http://download.akeneo.com/pim-community-standard-v2.2-latest-icecat.tar.gz
>
> sudo tar -xvzf pim-community-standard-v2.2-latest-icecat.tar.gz -C
>   /var/www/html/akeneo

I download it from above command in above given directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this command:

```
rm -rf /var/www/html/akeneo/
```